# Traces not propagating to GCP Cloud Trace from spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-sleuth, google-cloud-trace

I have a spring boot microservice which consumes and publishes messages from/to PubSub and is deployed on GKE. I am using spring stream binder for pubsub integration and Cloud Sleuth for generating traceId and spanId. TraceId and spanId are propagated to Stackdriver logging.
Now I want to send the trace data to Cloud trace. As per Spring GCP trace documentation, I have added gcp trace starter dependency but trace data are not being sent to Cloud trace.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I also tried adding this property spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=true. Application is not throwing an error/exception. Am I missing something in configuration and how can I debug this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enabled the Stackdriver Trace API for your project, as per https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/multi/multi__spring_cloud_sleuth.html?

Comment: yes trace api is enabled and I have also added Cloud trace agent role to service account.

Comment: Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/troubleshooting#no-data) for troubleshooting information of trace.